# How does one change the minimum value of a maya custom attribute?

Tags: python, scripting, maya

In maya, if I get a rig that has a custom attribute and that custom attribute has a minimum of 0.5, and then this rig (which I did not build) needs a minimum of 0.1, is there a way to adjust the minimum value, ideally in python? The only way I can see is using the Channel Editor and even then it tends to limit me to 0,0 if I try to adjust it. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use pymel, it is quite easy:

```
import pymel.core as pm
att = pm.PyNode("someNode.someAttribute")
att.setMin(.5)
```